# Rails 5 Autoload Lib folders

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autoload

Why modules and classes inside lib is not autoloaded? I am not able to include module in other classes or models.

```
module Data::State
  STATES = {new: 1, old: 2}
end
```

Error :-

> NameError: uninitialized constant Data::Video::State
>   while includes Data::State in model

Comment: Please provide the full path of your file, along with the model where you include it. That way we can identify the problem better. In any case, adding `config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/"]` to your application.rb could solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to specific environment configuration file, for example `config/environments/development.rb` if you want to load for `RAILS_ENV=development` only or `config/application.rb` if you want to autoload for all environments

```
config.autoload_paths += %W( #{config.root}/lib )
```